# How to encrypt private keys like OpenSSL?

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

When I generate a private Elliptic Curve with OpenSSL, with this command:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
```

I get something like this:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIHbAgEBBEGpyKy6t0i6cEdxETKfsXNmFA4oWLQrM1LaPdfiyGs13+DckCjskukK
NlbQYBb7gKIAAqj4vbmdCjTkoxnuXToqRKAHBgUrgQQAI6GBiQOBhgAEAHRbQ/Ow
rR0fjiLdS+wHgpGX3kIk1IdJwr6m18k8nkta7d6YCho555Tbru+17zrtEMasd5UH
YX8PRRtGaCD29aOzASUXOkwrmth4wLRsDQEe4qWAjATVvbw4LDP9Jz92OFXbEPwR
P3uNunAQ2grnBjNCXN5yF49nyK1lSZxscxv+OCM/
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

which has the same format to what I generate with a mix of NodeJS' Crypto module plus key-encoder:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIHcAgEBBEIBevCX7Zvo2G93UtPEl2ibpz71dXdjN/xMbwZBQwHukZJWwuKtJ8Sm
dn21nDV5uEa7mgiBu0X5BVvsN/Wr+TzoAD2gBwYFK4EEACOhgYkDgYYABABaycjM
EduL5R+bBY7T5WF+L314mfm2AZkKDs4EDkYWPupzbfE1qsQkjyPjh/JxMRU6nr9w
xJ7X9jSA6wy0dHNqSQFP+5SHOuJu32Da21qBIKU9Xaoy0CloGfRjEQAbg5N1h4uw
wKdMrY2a34dYn1eEe2YFzHKTFJPzOxyeKsDsFaafng==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now, when I encrypt it with AES256 by using this command

openssl ec -aes256 -in key.pem -out encrypted-key.pem

I get

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,96218C0F2D6F661750C994B319DD05FB

pdk5WCaaLL8+YU27QjHMRgNkNwgPfgqL2ZNx/73pBDiSekfEKn39XrllE+j0lEA/
jNt1v85bBl4GQR97Br1wYl0WyHRTMlJvyc1f+dRIG+Pyu2gt4bdWaXbuajn0suWG
EGNPKBQJNvY3+J010FQfVI45puC03gKA910ODSE3igNuAtSxoptmbD9DMr/2hj2y
BG1WarSvtX9P/eFw6sLVtou8iAD53lO41SA/ppHAbwuGdFwH9bA/LKlQUEHC3v2J
QJmEdt/1wYO4QLtFulDpNVd7nqGd3yn2/sZ1E5XBJ4E=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I get a similarly encrypted key with NodeJS' Crypto? or in other words, what's that format and how is it encrypted. With NodeJS' Crypto is trivial to do aes-256-cbc encryption, but I'm not sure how the passphrase is processed (hopefully pbkdf2) and how to reach that format. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Good one. I checked the encrypted key format, but that only shows the information of the resulting secret key (and otherwise it is just CBC with PKCS#5 padding). I presume a single round of `EVP_BytesToKey` to be used as key derivation, but that's OpenSSL specific.

Comment: The short of it is, you are seeing an encrypted key using [Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail: Part I: Message Encryption and Authentication Procedures](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1421.txt) from RFC 1421. Its *not* PKCS#8. Related, here's how the Crypto++ project achieves the interoperability with OpenSSL: [PEM Pack](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PeEM_Pack). The introduction to the wiki article is relevant to you and Node.js.

Comment: @jww: you should probably post that as an answer, as it is a very good lead. BTW, the actual link to PEM Pack should be https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PEM_Pack